# mod_rewrite condition if file exits not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following condition in my conf file:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/export/.*$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule .* /opencms/handle404?exporturi=%{REQUEST_URI}&%{QUERY_STRING} [P]
```

When I request the following file:

`http://www.somedomain.com/export/system/galleries_guardsman/pics/FPP/pencil-graphic-make-a-claim.png`

I can see in the rewrite log that it is matching the above conditions:

```
RewriteCond: input='/export/system/galleries_guardsman/pics/FPP/pencil-graphic-make-a-claim.png' pattern='^/export/.*$' => matched
RewriteCond: input='/val/data/webapps/opencms/export/system/galleries_guardsman/pics/FPP/pencil-graphic-make-a-claim.png' pattern='!-f' => matched
rewrite '/export/system/galleries_guardsman/pics/FPP/pencil-graphic-make-a-claim.png' -> '/opencms/handle404?exporturi=/export/system/galleries_guardsman/pics/FPP/pencil-graphic-make-a-claim.png&'
```

But the file `/val/data/webapps/opencms/export/system/galleries_guardsman/pics/FPP/pencil-graphic-make-a-claim.png` **actually exists**, so the RewriteRule should not be called.

I am sure I am missing something but have no idea what... Any help or insight would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^export/ /opencms/handle404?exporturi=%{REQUEST_URI} [QSA,P]
```

Without `%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}`.

Add `[QSA]` to append QUERY_STRING.

Comment: @anubhava Thank you !

Comment: I have tried both with %{DOCUMENT_ROOT} and without. I read that for the version we have (2.4.6) we need to use ${DOCUMENT_ROOT}.